# Filter (show and hide) Bricklayer.js items with Mixitup.js

Tags: javascript, css, mixitup

I'm using Bricklayer.js and Mixitup.js. Both are working fine. I can filter Bricklayer items (basically show and hide) by class name. However, due to the unique way Bricklayer works, in columns, I need Bricklayer to re-order (re-sort) it's layout.

The is the code I'm currently using:

```
// BRICKLAYER
var bricklayer = document.querySelector('.bricklayer')
if (bricklayer) {
    new Bricklayer(bricklayer)
}

// MIXITUP
var mixer = mixitup('.container', {
    callbacks: {
        onMixEnd: function(state, futureState) {
            console.log('Sorting')
            bricklayer.redraw
        }
    }
})
```

I think Bricklayer is redrawing, as all the elements are hidden by CSS. Is there any way around this at all?

Comment: how about a jsfiddle to show what you're talking about.

Comment: I can't get bricklayer to work properly in JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/04oxm16e

Comment: did yiu ever find a solution for this?